# How do I create a sticky sidebar in Joomla 4?

Tags: joomla-4.x, css, sidebar

I would like to create a sticky sidebar in Joomla 4. In other words, I would like to display a module next to an article in one of the sidebar positions. When the article scrolls up, the module must stop scrolling when it reaches the top of the page so that it remains visible no matter how far the article is scrolled.

I have tried using the CSS `position: sticky` property, but I can't get it to work.

I would be grateful for any help or pointers to an explanation of how to do this.

Comment: Here is a sample page showing what I would like to achieve: https://imago-1.com/articles/success-at-as-level.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get this to work ok.

When you edit the module, within the Advanced tab set a module class eg

```
Module Class   my-sticky-module
```

When this module is displayed it should then have "my-sticky-class" within the list of class attributes.

The in your user.css file define:

```
.my-sticky-module {
    top: 0;
    position:sticky;
}
```

You need to define the "top" as the stickiness can relate to either vertical or horizontal scrolling.

The user.css file should be in the css folder of your site template under the joomla media folder. So if you're using cassiopeia it should be in media/templates/site/cassiopeia/css/user.css.

You don't want to have any other modules under it in the sidebar though, as they'll scroll up to overwrite it.

Comment: Thank you, Robbie, for those helpful instructions. That is a nice easy way of assigning the sticky position to the module. What I did find is that, in addition to giving the module those styles, I had to give the containing column a style of `display: flex;`. Then it works nicely.